# How to import ReactCSSTransitionGroup using es6 syntax?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I'm trying to create Modal window to my React app, and I'm following [this](http://blog.tryolabs.com/2015/04/13/a-reusable-modal-component-in-react/) tutorial.

However, I got the following error

```
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `Modal`.
```

here is my code

```
import React from 'react'
import {ReactCSSTransitionGroup} from 'react-addons-css-transition-group'

const Modal = React.createClass ({

    render() {

        if (this.props.isOpen) {
            return (
                <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName={this.props.transitionName}>
                    <div className="modal">
                        {this.props.children}
                    </div>
                </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
            )    
        }

        else {
            return (
                <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName={this.props.transitionName} />
            )
        }
    }
})

module.exports = Modal
```

I installed react-addons-css-transition-group by `npm install --save react-addons-css-transition-group`

The problem is clearly ReactCSSTransitionGroup not being imported right, as replacing it with plain div doesn't throw any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the braces from `{ReactCSSTransitionGroup}`

```
import {ReactCSSTransitionGroup} from 'react-addons-css-transition-group'
```

should be

```
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group'
```

Also, you should provide a key for the children inside `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName={this.props.transitionName}>
                    <div className="modal" key="transitionGroup">
                        {this.props.children}
                    </div>
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```